# Exclude all .git or .svn folders from Spotlight index

Tags: macos, terminal, spotlight, indexing

I would like to exclude all the .git and .svn folders on my hardrive from the Spotlight index. I know I can manually add them through the GUI but since they are many of them, and often new ones, it would be difficult.

Is there any way to exclude a folder by name (rather than full path)? Or is there any way to exclude the folders using the command line (in which case, I could automatically find them and exclude them from time to time)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to exclude a folder using the command-line.

From [there](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63178/exclude-files-from-central-metadata-store) try this:

- Open a Terminal window
- Type

  `sudo defaults write /.Spotlight-V100/VolumeConfiguration.plist Exclusions -array-add 'path/to/exclude'`

So I guess you can try this using xargs' magic:

`sudo locate .git | xargs -I {} defaults write /.Spotlight-V100/VolumeConfiguration.plist Exclusions -array-add  {}`

You can check it worked using this:

`sudo defaults read /.Spotlight-V100/VolumeConfiguration.plist Exclusions`

You can remove all entries (there is no -array-remove option) using this:

`sudo defaults write /.Spotlight-V100/VolumeConfiguration.plist Exclusions -array`

**Be careful** with these commands, I don't know if there are side effects.

*I could not really check this worked for my .git folders since none of them were displayed by spotlight search before nor after running these commands.*