# How to include .git folders or files from .git folders in spotlight index?

Tags: spotlight, search, git, macos

There is a very old question about [excluding .git folders form Spotlight](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/112919/exclude-all-git-or-svn-folders-from-spotlight-index) index.

Apparently macOS today by default excludes content of .git folders, since on macOS Ventura, files residing in .git folders do not show in spotlight, which means they must have changed the behavior in recent years. With Apples poor or rather non-existent documentation that is hard to tell.

I have a .git folder with files I need to work with frequently and not being able to find those via Spotlight is really annoying.

Is there a way to include a specific .git folder or single files in Spotlight index and if yes, how is that done?

Comment: surely the files you want are not in the .git folder but checked out into the enclosing folder?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I have a folder called FolderName.git and in that folder there are files I would love to have indexed by spotlight.

Comment: The simple answer there is checkout those files with git. You should not be looking inside a.  .git directory (note it is just the extension,no name)

Comment: Or if they are checked out and Apple is being silly rename FolderName.git to FolderName